Comparing sigma-fields
All,
I am trying to justify that following sigma-fields are equal: $\sigma(X) = \sigma(X^2, \sin (X))$.
Of course, $\sigma(f(X)) \subset \sigma(X)$ (denoting the measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto (x^2, \sin(x)) \in \mathbb{R_+} \times [-1,1])$.
For the reverse statement, my intuition is that if "we know" $X^2$ and $\sin(X)$, we have two choices for $X = \pm \sqrt{X^2}$ and the sign of $\sin(X)$ allows to make a choice.
That is: $Y^{-1}(A)=f(X)^{-1}(A)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))$ for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R_+ \times [-1,1]})$ (Borel set) and we conclude using that $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
Though, if we were to compare  $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(X^2, \cos (X))$, my intuitive reasoning would be the same as above, but in that case, $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R_+})$ (which means that $\sigma(X^2, \cos (X)) = \sigma(|X|)$).
I suspect then my intuitive reasonning to be false. Any comment would be welcome.
Thanks!

Your intuitive reasoning actually leads to the conclusion that we can determine $X$ from the values of $X^2$ and $\sin X$, and so the sigma fields are indeed equal.
Intuitively, knowing $X^2$, we recover $|X|$ by taking the square root. Then since $\sin X$ is an odd function, it can take only one of two values, that is, $\pm \sin |X|$. The choice of sign in the $\pm$ determines also the sign of $X$, and thus we recover $X$ exactly.
For a formal proof, it will suffice to invert $f$. Now note that $\frac{z}{|\sin \text{arcsin}\sqrt{y}|}\sqrt{y}$ is an exact inverse to $f: x \to (y, z) = (x^2, \sin x)$.
Of course, we cannot do the same with $\cos X$ as it is an even function, and so the sign of $\cos X$ gives us no clue as to the sign of $X$.
